# Why Twilio's Alpha ID doesn't support sending SMS to the USA?

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api

I'm just curious: is there any reason why the USA is on the short list of countries that don't support Twilio's Alphanumeric ID?

Full list can be find here:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I know this is down to limitations with carriers in the USA and there's nothing we can do about it. That's all I know!